# How can I quickly rank up in Battlefield 3?

Tags: battlefield-3

What is the best method for ranking up in Battlefield 3?

I have been told 2 different methods so far:

- Play as recon on team deathmatch, then use gadgets to spot team mates
- Play as assault on Metro (Conquest), and concentrate on healing/reviving team mates

As a recon, I am struggling to get a decent score per game (in the range of a couple of thousand at best).

As an assault I can get around 7-10k per game.

Is there anything I can do to improve my score in the methods above?

Are there other effective methods (game modes/maps/class combinations)?

Comment: Play on the small maps like operation Metro. That alone makes a big difference for me.

Answer (score 2):

This highly depends on why you want to rank. Just your player level or your class level or specific gun unlocks?

- Player: universal weapons & perks
- Class: class weapons gadgets
- Gun: specific gun gadgets

Supporting your team is the way to go imho.

- Recon: T-Ugs in crowded area
- Assault: reviving and healing
- Support: dropping ammo

Preferably you want to do this in a small infantery map. You have way more contact and things to do.
Also ticket count plays a role:

- Normal or slight increased ticketcount you get some extra points for each won game + other ribbons.
- High ticket will likely result in an unbalanced fight over time, and you will have the risk of disconnecting

I prefer Rush Operation Metro. Most of the time it's really crowded near the stairs.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're trying to do; if you want your player weapons ranked up go play **Team Death Match**. If you're wanting to level up your tanks, helicopters, and other vehicles, play **Conquest** or **Rush**. Now, if you're looking to upgrade everything, then you just need to play the game on any game mode.